# Assembly Language: Comparing user input fails

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning assembly and while it is simple, something is not working. I wrote a code which takes a number as input and compares it to two. If they are equal the code should print "Entered number is 2", if it does not equal, simply continue and exit. The code works except the cmp and jmp instructions. The code has enough comments to understand it:

```
section .data                           ;Data segment
   userMsg db 'Please enter a number: ' ;Ask the user to enter a number
   lenUserMsg equ $-userMsg             ;The length of the message
   dispMsg db 'You have entered: '
   lenDispMsg equ $-dispMsg  
     dispMsg1 db 'You have entered 2 '
   lenDispMsg1 equ $-dispMsg1                 


section .bss           ;Uninitialized data
   num resb 8

section .text          ;Code Segment
   global _start

_start:                ;User prompt
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, userMsg
   mov edx, lenUserMsg
   int 80h

   ;Read and store the user input
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 2
   mov ecx, num  
   mov edx, 8          ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
   int 80h

   ;Output the message 'The entered number is: '
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, dispMsg
   mov edx, lenDispMsg
   int 80h  

   ;Output the number entered
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, num
   mov edx, 5
   int 80h  

;compate the register ecx, which holds num, with 2. 
   cmp ecx , 2
   JE L1 ;if it equals 2, print it is 2
   jmp L2 ;if not exit

   L1:
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, dispMsg1
   mov edx, lenDispMsg1
   int 80h  

   ; Exit code
   L2:
   mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 80h
```

Comment: You read the input as text but then try compare as integer. Also `ecx` is holding the address.

Comment: how can i read it as int?

Comment: You can't. You need to convert from string to int yourself, or do the comparison on the text form.

Comment: now that does indeed make sense, but can i do the conversion efficiently?